# Android Emulator ISO?

Tags: android, emulation

I am trying to setup a testing environment for the development of java apps.
I do not have any dedicated server right now and I am using one KVM VPS to write a code and on another one I am running Android x86 8.1 RC2 in Debug Mode to catch the contents of */data/log.txt*.  Everything works nice and smooth.
Yet right now I need to test the app on Android 9.0 Pie.  There is no ISO images of Android x86-pie yet, only sources.  So I wonder if I should try to build myself Android x86 9.0 from the sources or there is another option..?
*(I tried to install Bliss OS, but failed: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=80086490&postcount=1070 )*

So apparently there is Android Emulator available: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/08/emulator-29110-canary-android-q-beta-6.html but it requires /dev/kvm *(which means that I probably should run it on dedicated server?)*.
How this emulator works?  Is it possible to make an ISO image and install it on VPS?

**Edit:**
This is the Android 28 system image that sdkmanager provides:
[image: android system img]
I wonder if it is possible to convert this one into ISO for installation on VPS.

**Edit2:**
Tried Android x86 9.0.0 r34... It doesn't work yet.
https://github.com/android-x86/android-x86.github.io/issues/52#issuecomment-524590033